# bash list all directories, subdirectories, folders, subfolders in then output to a separate file

Tags: android, linux, bash, sed, command

I'm trying to create two very similar scripts.  One script is to list all files in a directory and then subdirectories, subdirectories of subdirectories, and so on and so on until there are no more directories and then output the info to a log file with the path name starting from the directory I started from.  The other script is to do exactly the same as above, but instead of the directories, I need it to list all the files within those directories and subdirectories.  I also need the path names starting from the directory I started from.  They both need to output in separate log files, however.

I need to do this in either sed commands or bash commands compatible with android.

/system/ denotes the directory I want to start from

This outputs just the directories in /system/ and successfully makes a log file:

```
LOG_FILE=/data/local/log.log;
for d in /system/*; do [[ -f "$d" ]] || echo "$d" "$d"| tee -a $LOG_FILE; done
```

This outputs just the files in /system/ and successfully makes a log file:

```
LOG_FILE=/data/local/log.log;
for f in /system/*; do [[ -d "$f" ]] || echo "$f" "$f"| tee -a $LOG_FILE; done
```

Unfortunately I've been unsuccessful searching here or anywhere else to find how to do it properly.  I'm almost certain I can't do it recursively in the Android system I'm working with.  I think that all I have to work with is sed and bash in a limited manner.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** So I forgot to add that I need to add lines to the beginning and ending of each line in the file in the fashion below, but with the above changes i need.

```
LOG_FILE=/local/log.log;
tmp1="cp"
tmp2=tmp
tmp3=test
for f in /system/*; do [[ -d "$f" ]] || echo $tmp1 $tmp2/$tmp3"$f" "$f"| tee -a $LOG_FILE; done
```

So it would output like this with /system/file.txt being the path i need to replicate (denoted by "$f"):

```
cp tmp/test/system/file.txt system/file.txt
cp tmp/test/system/file2.txt system/file2.txt
```

Comment: There are no folders and/or subfolders in UNIX. There are directories and files. That other terminology is from Windows or DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add text in the beginning and end of line, use xargs with the find

```
find /system/ -type f|xargs -i echo "BEGIN" {} "END" > $LOG_FILE
```

Update:

```
#¡/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="log"
tmp1="cp"
tmp2=tmp
tmp3=test

for i in `find /system/ -type f`;
do
  [[ -d "$i" ]] || echo $tmp1 $tmp2/$tmp3"$i" "$i"| tee -a $LOG_FILE;  
done
```

Output is

```
cp tmp/test/dir/file dir/file
```

Comment: If I wanted to exclude files or directories/subdirectories in your updated function from being added to the LOG_FILE, how would that be done?

Comment: You can add a if else loop to skip any specific file `if [[ "$i" =~ README\.md$ ]]; then ## do nothing; else ## do something; fi`. But if you have a long list of files, I guess using something like [Perl File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is the best option.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for the directories:

```
find /system/ -type d -print > $LOG_FILE
```

and this should get you the files list:

```
find /system/ -type f -print > $LOG_FILE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to add some vital information in my script so I added the edit in the bottom of the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the directory for files and dirs in one-shot:

```sh
find . \( -type d -printf "%p\n" \) -o \( -type f -printf  "cp %p tmp/test/%p\n" \) >out.log
```

and use different *c-style* [output format directives](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Format-Directives.html#Format-Directives) for customizing your output.

Answer (score 0):

the following one liner walks level by level from the start point till the deepest level

```
let d=1; continue=0; while [[ $continue -eq 0 ]]; do find <start path> -mindepth $d -maxdepth $d -type f -exec echo "<Your message> {}" \; | grep . ; continue=$? ;(( d++ ));  done;
```

depends on your need you can choose between `-type f` and `-type d`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a lot of processing to do so if I were you'd I'd use `find` to get the list of files and their type:

```
$ find tmp -printf '%y %p\n'
d tmp
f tmp/file001
f tmp/file002
f tmp/file003
d tmp/foo
f tmp/foo/file004
```

and then you can do whatever you like with then, e.g.:

```
$ find tmp -printf '%y %p\n' | awk '$1=="d"{sub(/^../,"");print}'
tmp
tmp/foo

$ find tmp -printf '%y %p\n' | awk '$1=="f"{sub(/^../,"");print}'
tmp/file001
tmp/file002
tmp/file003
tmp/foo/file004

$ find tmp -printf '%y %p\n' | awk -F'/' '{print NF, $0}' | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
d tmp
d tmp/foo
f tmp/file001
f tmp/file002
f tmp/file003
f tmp/foo/file004

$ find tmp -printf '%y %p\n' | awk -F'/' '{print NF, $0}' | sort -k1,1nr | cut -d' ' -f2-
f tmp/foo/file004
d tmp/foo
f tmp/file001
f tmp/file002
f tmp/file003
d tmp
```

You cant really see it well from the example but those last commands are sorting by depth.

All of the above will fail if you have files with newlines in their names.